# constexpr function not calculate value in compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, compile-time, gcc4.8

I want to compare meta programming and use of constexpr in c++0x.
then I write a fib function in both model.
when I use meta programming model, answer print out very fast because it calculated in compile time. but when I use constexpr funcion it calculate value in run time, not in compile time.
I using g++( gcc ) 4.8 .can any body help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NUM 42

template <unsigned int N>
struct Fibonacci {
    enum { value = Fibonacci<N - 1>::value + Fibonacci<N - 2>::value };
};

template <>
struct Fibonacci<1> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

template <>
struct Fibonacci<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

constexpr unsigned int fib(unsigned int n)
{
    return (n > 1 ? fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) : 1 );
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Meta_fib(NUM)      : " << Fibonacci<NUM>::value << endl; // compile time :)
    cout << "Constexpr_fib(NUM) : " << fib(NUM) << endl;        // run time :-?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Both look compile-time to me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fe7e66ca805e846)

Comment: Isn't the idea of constexpr is that it works in compile time?

Comment: How do you know it calculates the value at runtime? Have you looked at the assembly?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Compiling with gcc, its evaluated at runtime. Although you can simply force compile time evaluation with `constexpr unsigned i = fib(NUM);`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You just have to run it. You can see the cycles spinning before it prints the output. :)

Comment: @juanchopanza: just a simple way ;) when i run this code, meta programming model answer fast , but constexpr model answer very slow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the reason is that `constexpr` is not guaranteed to execute at compile-time. To enforce compile-time evaluation, you have to assign it to a compile-time alias. Like,

`enum {i = fib(NUM)};`

Comment: Any way to make it be force evaluated even not to assign to a const variable?

Comment: Not sure I understood the question correctly. Are you asking for another way to guarantee compile-time evaluation besides using it in a 'const context'? The answer to this question is, probably, 'No'.

Comment: For example I want to pass the result of a `constexpr function`(A) as a parameter to another `normal function`(B) but I have no way to make the result const. A solution is to involve an intermediate `const variable` to hold the result and then pass the `const variable` to function B which is what I don't want

Comment: Well, I don't think there's a better way to do that, if you have to absolutely guarantee compile-time evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

With gcc, at least, you can get the constexpr value to be computed at compile time by making it a static variable:

```
static const unsigned fibNUM = fib(NUM);
```

As I read the standard, it's still allowed to compute the value at startup, but in practice it will be computed at compile time.

Comment: that's cool but why not add just 4 chars const->constexpr and guarantee everything?

Comment: @RiaD: Do you have a standard quote which substantiates that guarantee?

Answer (score 1):

A simple test to see if your `constexpr` are really being done at compile-time is to use an `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, Fibonacci<5>::value> arr;
std::array<int, fib(5)> arr2;
```

[gcc has no complaints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96cee1c002e492b3).

See this [comment by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time-stackoverflow):

> ... according to the standard a constexpr function may be evaluated at
>   compiler time or run time unless it is used as a constant expression,
>   in which case it must be evaluated at compile-time. To guarantee
>   compile-time evaluation, we must either use it where a constant
>   expression is required (e.g., as an array bound or as a case label) or
>   use it to initialize a constexpr. I would hope that no self-respecting
>   compiler would miss the optimization opportunity to do what I
>   originally said: "A constexpr function is evaluated at compile time if
>   all its arguments are constant expressions."

Comment: That, however, will never cause the compiler to complain. Using a constexpr as template parameter simply _forces_ the compiler to evaluate it at compile-time. Which is of course possible if the function meets the strict requirements for `constexpr` (otherwise the compiler complains much earlier anyway). It may, however, still evaluate the same function at runtime in a different location (notably gcc does just that! You would think that once-compiletime, the compiler is smart enough to remember this for all uses. It's not.)

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` is not guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time. This means, compiler can choose whether to evaluate at compile time or at run time.
You can try to assign it to a compile time constant and check like this...

```
const long i = fib(NUM);// here i should be initialized at the time of 
                        // declaration
cout << "Meta_fib(NUM)      : " << Fibonacci<NUM>::value << endl; 
cout << "Constexpr_fib(NUM) : " << i << endl;
```